# Why is "sea" used in "quién sea él" but not "es"?

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, conjugación

I tried to translate "I don't care who he is" into Spanish, and I got this:

> No me importa quién **sea** él

This sounds strange. **sea** is the present subjunctive (or imperative) conjugation of **ser**, which doesn't look right to me. I thought I should use **es**.

What is the difference, in this case, between indicative and subjunctive? Is it the same case about "*dónde*" (where) and "*qué*" (what)?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context?  Both are perfectly fine, and context is needed.  In general through, *quién + ind.* = **who**, and *quién + subj.* = **whoever**

Comment: @guifa I guess I have the answer. The sentence says *I don't care*, so *whoever* fits better (since *I don't care*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say there's a knock on the door.  You ask

> ¿Quién es?

Now let's say the phone rings, and you tell your brother, who's visiting and sitting next to the phone, not to answer it because you don't want to be interrupted, and you think it would be fine for whoever it is to leave a voicemail.  You might say

> No me importa quién sea. | I don't care who it is.

We use the subjunctive here, and it's kind of like saying "I don't care who it might be."  (Here, we don't know who is calling, so there's uncertainty, which requires the subjunctive.)

Last scenario:  Let's say the phone rings.  You know it's your son calling for the umpteenth time that afternoon, but your brother doesn't know that, and wants to answer it, saying that it might be something important.  You respond

> Ya se quién es, y no me importa.

There's no uncertainty here, hence no subjunctive.

Comment: That's a nice answer, @aparente001. I only saw it after posting mine. The examples make the difference pretty clear.

Comment: So in short, is it "subj. = uncertainty (whoever)" and "ind. = certainty (who)"?

Comment: @iBug - That sounds reasonable.

Comment: Does the same apply to *dónde* and *qué*? Is it true that "*dónde estés* = wherever" and "*qué sea* = whatever"?

Comment: @iBug - That sounds good too.  Examples: *Donde tú estés, yo estaré contigo.  No me importa dónde estés ahorita, debes venirte a la casa ya.*

Comment: @aparente001 Let's refine our posts. I've merged the question about *dónde* and *qué* into my question, and it'd be good if you merge your response into your answer :)

Comment: @iBug - I am reluctant to expand my answer.  Spanish textbooks have a whole chapter on when to use the subjunctive, and I don't want to reproduce all that.  I just wanted to give you a targeted answer to the specific thing you were having trouble understanding.  Basically, regarding what you asked about, any sentence that starts out "No me importa" is probably going to need the subjunctive, and there are tons of ways this could play out, e.g. "No me importa **adónde vayas** después de la escuela, siempre y cuando me traes los tomates que necesito para la cena antes de las 5:00."

Answer (score 5):

There are cases in which both indicative and subjunctive work, though with a subtle difference of meaning. In this specific case, in which identity is involved:

> (1) ... quién sea él.
>
> (2) ... quién es él.

one thing is clear: he does have an identity (a name, a role), which the speaker is not interested in discovering or in considering.

To understand the difference above, let's see a different pair of sentences:

- No me importa que **llueva**. (We don't know if it's raining.)
- No me importa que **llueve**. (We know it's raining.)

We can thus see that the subjunctive casts some doubt as to the truth of the clause, while the indicative provides certainty.

If we apply this distinction to your pair of sentences, if the speaker uses (1) he wants to imply that he is not willing to believe that the other person is who he claims to be. If the speaker uses (2), he implies that he will not challenge his identity, hierarchy, authority, etc.

As a result, sentence (1) may be more pejorative: the speaker does not care who he is and, even if he finds out, he indicates that he is reluctant to believe it.

Comment: Gracias. Both answer looks brilliant and I'm not sure which to accept.